# Swift iOS how to remove top padding UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    scrollView.collectionViewLayout = layout
    scrollView.delegate = self
    scrollView.dataSource = self
    scrollView.contentInset = .zero
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = .zero
    scrollView.isDirectionalLockEnabled = true
    scrollView.register(UINib(nibName: "RadioView", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "RadioViewController")
}
lazy var layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    layout.headerReferenceSize = .zero
    layout.sectionInset = .zero
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.horizontal
    return layout
}()
```

background Color Red is `UICollectionView`

backgorund Color Black is `UICollectionViewCell`

[image]

i want move Cell to left top

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If it's not a **Layout constraint** problem, than:

```
collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
```

It is also possible that you have implemented:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        //...
    }
```

In that case you need to set the methods return value `top` property to `0`

Comment: return .zero but
get same result

Comment: @Adam, then you might want to recheck `UICollectionView` Autolayout constraints. Is it Storyboard-based?

Comment: Can you run application on simulator, open the screen we are talking about and then press "Debug View Hierarchy" button and make a screenshot?

Comment: add screenshot in last at post , Is that what you need?

Comment: Do you have any UICollectionview headers?

Comment: header is zero and 
I uploaded the screenshot again for the Debug View Hierarchy

Comment: What is that 20 pt Y which is selected?

Comment: 20 is TopLayoutGuide.bottom 0 , i changed superView.bottom 0 but no effect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182347/discussion-between-llb-and-adam).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting these two property of `UIViewController` in `viewDidLoad`

```
extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

Please check the header size in the storyboard, try setting them to zero.

Comment: In my case it has no effect.

Comment: did you checked the header size in storyboard size inspector ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the problem set the value of `Y component` to zero

[image: Problem is here]